# How do I add new data to datacube using socket in trading vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
<trading-vue :data="dc" :extensions="ext"/>
</template>
<script>

import TradingVue from 'trading-vue-js'
import XP from 'tvjs-xp'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: { TradingVue },
    data() {
        return {
            ext: Object.values(XP),
            dc: new DataCube(...)
        }
    }
}

</script>
How can I listen to instant data with socket and update the chart in Trading vue js?
```

For example, how can I add the data taken in the candle or line chart to the chart up-to-date?